# touch screen / terminal / computer for customers

Tags: touchscreen, touchpad

I'm looking for a cheap solution that provides the following:

I would like to have that the customers can swap through our range of products in the local store and when they want to know more of a product, they can click on it and more information will be provided. Hence, a video/trailer to implement would also be nice.
A regular windows OS could be do it but I don't want the customers to go into settings and so on by accident.

Size screen is probably ok when >=15".
Is there any hardware (and/or combined with software) which fulfills this? Let it be something around 100-200 €.

Comment: This question is branching out into software solution management, content management and delivery, network and hardware security, and possibly custom programming, all in addition to the hardware request. It is way beyond the scope of this forum. You might want to look into hiring someone since this is a business environment use case that we're looking at. Best of luck.

Comment: You're probably going to be looking for something along the lines of an [embedded system](http://www.embedsolution.com/common/download/HowtoBuy.pdf), but my experiences with these are limited. I am quite certain that you are not going to find these types of systems on the wider consumer market because they typically tailor the system to your needs on an individual basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is probably more price range than anything else.  The touchscreen monitor is the expense, and takes up a large portion of your budget. [For instance, this one takes up half your budget, and it's an inexpensive option by your requirements.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07586J8P7)  Another one [takes up much more.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007948V24)

Windows 8 - 10 has the ability to run as a Kiosk, and you can find some [tutorials to teach you how to set it up that way.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-AEZUJx9Bg)  This will handle your worries about user access.

You may wish to consider the less expensive option of using [QR Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code).  QR codes next to your product allows anyone with a smartphone that can read a barcode (which is pretty much all of them) to auto-link to a website of your choosing.  Ideally, this is your website that has been programmed, made adaptive to mobile, and hosted for you, to which your in-store screens would probably have been pointing, anyway.  This gives you less to maintain, less up-front expense, and when bored children start playing with screens, it will be their own screens or those of their parents and not your expensive product terminals.